# How to have code quality analysis for Angular in Jenkins?

Tags: angular, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, analysis

Is there any tool to integrate with Jenkins?
I have the testing and coverage but I could't find any related with analysis code for Angular 2/4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can use SonarCube with a plugin for Typescript and integrate SonarCube with Jenkins. This plugins works fine with Angular 2/4:

- [SonarTsPlugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin)